# Вписывание изображений в блок

Tags: javascript, css

Подскажите как можно сделать вписывание изображений в зависимости от их количества в блок ?

Что-то подобное реализованное при добавлении картинок к посту на стене Вконтакте.

Если картинка одна добавлена, то она занимает ширину 100%, если две, то обе примерно по 50% занимают, если 3 картинки, то 1 становится самой большой, а две другие добавляются слева с высотой, равной половине от первой, и так далее. Разные комбинации для разного количества изображений при добавлении динамически.

[image: вот пример компановки]

Подскажите как это можно реализовать, не прибегая к конструкции `if else` для каждого количества изображений. Спасибо

Comment: Насколько я знаю, во ВКонтакте можно максимум 10 (или 5, я не помню точно, но ограниченное количество) картинок добавить. Почему бы не воспользоваться и `switch`?

Comment: Ну а без `switch` - просто математика. Как ты и сказал, при добавлении 3-х, первой дать 50% пространства (например), а остальным по 25%. Никаких проблем. При 4-х  (в зависимости от количества картинок) даешь по циклу скалькулированные свойства картинкам. Без `switch`, конечно.

Comment: @VostokSisters немножечко подробнее по поводу switch. Я как понимаю с начала подсчитывается количество изображений, если их например 3 то выбирается switch 3 и там уже для каждого изображений высчитывается ширина и прописываются свойства. Для первого одно, для второго другое, для третьего третье ? Тогда получается что на вариант который я привел выше в картинке выйдет уйма кода в одном switch или я немного не так понимаю. Спасибо

Comment: Я начал уже было писать и решил протестировать алгоритм во ВК. Если убирать картинки из приложенных в пост и добавлять, то ширина и высота первых будет разной и не всегда самая первая имеет ширину. "Комбинаций" там как-то нет, скрипт работает... рандомно, что ли. Иногда (даже если просто начать перетаскивать картинки драг энд дропом в посте до того, как их отправить) первая делается на 90%, а остальные в самом низу маленькими приводятся. Возможно, есть и рандом. Это касательно скрипта в ВК.

Comment: Вообще говоря, ВК скрипт на добавление фотографий весьма сложный) Много нюансов с работой конкретно размеров фоток, чтобы правильно их скомпановать. Я бы мог и написать, но очень и очень лень (: Просто скажу, что можно обойтись и простым перебором картинок по циклу  и с учетом их количества  к добавлению, устанавливать размер отображения первым картинкам, а остальным - свой.

Comment: @VostokSisters Спасибо большое за совет. Воспользуюсь вашим советом по поводу перебора в цикле, он спасает в ситуации

Comment: пацаны, рекомендую статью https://github.com/xieranmaya/blog/issues/6. один китаец очень угорел и прошел, кажется, через все круги ада, чтобы это сделать на чистом цсс

Comment: это же элементарный флэкс ? нет ?

Answer (score 0):

```css
div,figure
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
div.cover
{ 
    border:2px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
    width:calc(100%);
    height:calc(98%);
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row nowrap;
    background:hsla(120,80%,50%,1);
}
div.cover .div_figure
{
    width:35%;
    height:20em;
    margin-right:1%;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex:1 1 35%;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
    background:hsla(0,0%,40%,1);
}
.div_figure figure
{ 
    border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
    background: url("http://гремячье.рф/array/s4_2.jpeg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
.div_figure figure:nth-of-type(1)
{
    flex:1 1 98%;
}
.div_figure figure:nth-of-type(2)
{ 
    flex:1 1 49%;
}
.div_figure figure:nth-of-type(3)
{
    flex:1 1 49%;
}

div.cover .div_figure_one
{
    flex:1 1 35%;
    width:35%;
    height:20em;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,0%,1);
    background:hsla(0,0%,40%,1);
}
.div_figure_one figure
{ 
    border:1px solid hsla(0,0%,100%,1);
    background: url("http://гремячье.рф/array/s4_2.jpeg") no-repeat center center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
}
.div_figure_one figure:nth-of-type(1)
{
    flex:1 1 49%;
}
.div_figure_one figure:nth-of-type(2)
{ 
    flex:1 1 49%;
}
.div_figure_one figure:nth-of-type(3)
{
    flex:1 1 32%;
}
.div_figure_one figure:nth-of-type(4)
{ 
    flex:1 1 33%;
}
.div_figure_one figure:nth-of-type(5)
{
    flex:1 1 33%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cover">  
 <div class="div_figure">
    <figure ></figure>
    <figure ></figure>
    <figure ></figure>
 </div>
   
  <div class="div_figure_one">
   <figure ></figure>
   <figure ></figure>
   <figure ></figure>
   <figure ></figure>
   <figure ></figure>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Подберите размеры , вполне может работать. Элементы можно скрывать/показывать через классы или через js.